# How to enable Async/Wait in SPFx Typescript, tslint: Missing semicolon, TS1005: ',' expected, TS2304: Cannot find name 'await'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, typescript

I am trying to use `async` / `await` for developing a SPFx WebPart. The sample `react-async-await-sp-pnp-js` in `sp-dev-fx-webparts` compiles and runs fine on my computer. When I try to use `async` / `await`, Visual Code highlights the `await` keyword stating *Cannot find name 'await'*, the `async` keyword prefixing the functon appears good. When running `gulp test` I get the following errors:

```
Warning - tslint - src\...ts(74,35): error semicolon: Missing semicolon
Error - typescript - src\...ts(73,35): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - typescript - src\...ts(73,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'await'.
```

My webpart shows the following versions:

```
Build tools version: 2.5.3
Node version: v6.11.0
```

The *react-async-await-sp-pnp-js* shows the following versions:

```
Build tools version: 2.7.0
Node version: v6.11.0
```

Both *tsconfig.json* appear identical to me.

In *package.json* some versions slightly differ, and my webpart has no reference to *sp-client-base*, wich seems to only export `Compare`.

My *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "ilog",
  "version": "0.0.27",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/immutability-helper": "^2.0.15",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "moment": "^2.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/microsoft-ajax": "0.0.32",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "@types/sharepoint": "^2013.1.6",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  }
}
```

The *react-async-await-sp-pnp-js* package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-async-await-sp-pnp-js",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-client-base": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.0.0",
"@types/react": "0.14.46",
"@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "react": "15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "15.5.4",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.0.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated :-)

*Update:*
Here the code I am trying to get running:

```
private async loadScripts(): Promise<void> {

    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        if(this._context) {
            resolve();
        }

        const response = await this.loadScript(layoutsUrl + 'init.js', 'Sod');
        resolve();
    });

private loadScript(url: string, globalObjectName: string): Promise<void> {
```

Comment: Can you share your code which uses the async/await methods ?

Comment: I added the code. The async keywords gets accepted, then come the error messages for the async keyword.

Comment: Can you modify the `loadScript` function as as `private async loadScript(url: string, globalObjectName: string): Promise<void> {`  and check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function. You are using `await` in the callback for your returned Promise which is not marked as `async`. Here is how you can make the callback `async`:

```
private async loadScripts(): Promise<void> { 
    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
        if(this._context) {
            resolve();
        }

        const response = await this.loadScript(layoutsUrl + 'init.js', 'Sod');
        resolve();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much :-) Thanks for all your great efforts including your blog :-)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help